# Extract contour area from image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, contour

I got some questions about segmentation of contoured image. For example i got [cable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoyYF.jpg) and i can contour this image with threshold and drawcontour function with code in down below. [Contoured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UipcF.jpg), [threshold image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5W3C.jpg). My questions are i want to extract this cable and read rgb code. Any advice could be great! Thanks.

```
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, thresh_img = cv2.threshold(gray_image, trs, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh_img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cv2.drawContours(im2, contours, -1, red, cnt)
    cv2.imshow(winName, im2)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what area you want to extract?

Comment: @littlecat I need to read the color by separating the cable in the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cv2.contourArea(contours)` more information [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) and [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the area inside some polygon "contour" using shoelace formula

The Idea is to calculate the are incrementally by summing/subtracting the area between polygon sides and on the axis , after one complete loop though the polygon contour you the result of summation/subtraction will be the area inside the polygon

```
j = numPoints-1       
for (uint_fast8_t i=0; i<numPoints; i++)
      {

        area = area +  (contour[j][0]+contour[i][0]) * (contour[j][1]-contour[i][1]);
        area1 = area1 +  (contour[j][0]*contour[i][1]) - (contour[j][1]*contour[i][0]); //different form for the formula
        j = i;  //j is previous vertex to i
      }
```

area= area/2;
area1= area1/2;  //sign of area depend on direction of rotation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea.html

https://www.mathopenref.com/coordpolygonarea2.html

for python

https://www.101computing.net/the-shoelace-algorithm/

Comment: Please post more than just links in your answers and explain the content in them in case the links might not work anymore in the future.